# JavaFX error while loading scene

Tags: java, javafx

I have an issue, It's very hard to explain but I will do my utmost best to describe it the best way I could. I have this FXML (Scene) in my project (see [Luggage overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9iIz.png)). When I click on "Edit selected luggage" it opens up a new FXML file and displays it as a popup. However for some odd reason when I try to use a .setText or anything else to change the input fields that appear on the window after clicking the "Edit selected luggage" button it gives me an error of the following:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fastenyourseatbelt.view.luggageController.editSelected(luggageController.java:102)
    ... 41 more
```

This is the method I use to make the scene popup:

```
public class popup {

    public void open(String scene, String title, Class className, Button btn) {
        try {
            Stage stage;
            Parent root;

            stage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(className.getResource(scene));

            root = loader.load();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.setTitle(title);
            stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            stage.initOwner(btn.getScene().getWindow());
            stage.showAndWait();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(luggageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
package fastenyourseatbelt.view;

import fastenyourseatbelt.dao.luggageDao;
import fastenyourseatbelt.helper.changeScene;
import fastenyourseatbelt.helper.popup;
import fastenyourseatbelt.model.Luggage;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class luggageController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Button test;
    @FXML
    TableView<Luggage> AllLuggageView;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Luggage, String> flightNumber;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Luggage, String> firstName;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Luggage, String> lastName;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Luggage, String> colorName;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Luggage, String> brandName;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Luggage, String> weight;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Luggage, String> state;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Luggage, String> comment;

    @FXML
    Button deleteLuggage;
    @FXML
    Button editLuggage;
    @FXML
    TextField editWeight;

    luggageDao luggageDao = new luggageDao();
    Luggage luggage = new Luggage();
    changeScene scene = new changeScene();
    genericController generic = new genericController();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    }

    public void removeLuggage() {
        System.out.print(luggage.getFlightNr());

    }

    public Luggage getSelected() {
        Luggage selectedItem = AllLuggageView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        return selectedItem;
    }
    popup popup = new popup();

    public void loadLuggageTable() {
        Collection luggageList = luggageDao.getAllLuggage();
        flightNumber.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("flightNumber"));
        flightNumber.setMinWidth(100);
        firstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("travelerFirstName"));
        firstName.setMinWidth(100);
        lastName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("travelerLastName"));
        lastName.setMinWidth(100);
        colorName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("colorName"));
        colorName.setMinWidth(50);
        brandName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("brandName"));
        brandName.setMinWidth(100);
        weight.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("weight"));
        weight.setMinWidth(100);
        state.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Status"));
        state.setMinWidth(100);
        comment.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("comment"));
        comment.setMinWidth(100);
        AllLuggageView.getItems().setAll(luggageList);
    }

    public void editSelected() {

        editWeight.setText("sdfsfsdf");
        popup.open("EditLuggage.fxml", "Edit luggage", this.getClass(), editLuggage);

    }

    public void closePopup() {
        popup.close(test);
    }

    @FXML
    public void back(MouseEvent event) {
        scene.changeScene(event, this.getClass(), generic.getPreviousScreen(), changeScene.Action.BACK);
    }
}
```

Editluggage.FXML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import java.lang.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="634.0" prefWidth="1037.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fastenyourseatbelt.view.luggageController">
       <children>
          <ChoiceBox fx:id="editFlightnumber" layoutX="297.0" layoutY="202.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="163.0" />
          <Text layoutX="183.0" layoutY="267.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Size" />
          <Text layoutX="184.0" layoutY="314.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Weight" />
          <TextField id="editWeight" fx:id="editWeight" layoutX="297.0" layoutY="297.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="163.0" text="ddd" />
          <Text layoutX="183.0" layoutY="220.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Flight number" />
          <Button layoutX="556.0" layoutY="452.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: red;" text="Save" textFill="WHITE" />
          <Button layoutX="441.0" layoutY="452.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="48.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" text="Exit" textFill="WHITE" />
          <ImageView fitHeight="119.0" fitWidth="114.0" layoutX="462.0" layoutY="35.0">
             <image>
                <Image url="@../Downloads/user-group-add-512.png" />
             </image>
          </ImageView>
          <Text fx:id="displayTo" layoutX="713.0" layoutY="220.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="To" />
          <Text fx:id="displayFrom" layoutX="540.0" layoutY="220.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="From" />
          <ChoiceBox fx:id="editSize" layoutX="297.0" layoutY="249.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="163.0" />
          <ChoiceBox fx:id="editBrand" layoutX="297.0" layoutY="338.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="163.0" />
          <Text layoutX="185.0" layoutY="355.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Brand" />
          <Text layoutX="184.0" layoutY="398.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Color" />
          <ChoiceBox fx:id="editColor" layoutX="296.0" layoutY="381.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="163.0" />
          <TextArea fx:id="editComment" layoutX="540.0" layoutY="331.0" prefHeight="86.0" prefWidth="316.0" />
       </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

LuggageMenuScherm.FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fastenyourseatbelt.view.luggageController">
   <children>
      <Button id="lostLuggage" fx:id="lostLuggage" layoutX="121.0" layoutY="103.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="New Lost Luggage" />
      <Button id="foundLuggage" fx:id="foundLuggage" layoutX="272.0" layoutY="103.0" mnemonicParsing="false"  text="New Found Luggage" />
      <Button id="backButton" fx:id="backButton" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="16.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#back" text="Back" />
      <TableView id="AllLuggageView" fx:id="AllLuggageView" layoutX="121.0" layoutY="158.0" prefHeight="506.0" prefWidth="1039.0">
         <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="flightNumber" prefWidth="75.0" text="Flight number" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="firstName" prefWidth="75.0" text="First name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="lastName" prefWidth="75.0" text="Last name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="colorName" prefWidth="75.0" text="Color" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="brandName" prefWidth="75.0" text="Brand" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="weight" prefWidth="75.0" text="Weight" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="state" prefWidth="75.0" text="State" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="comment" prefWidth="75.0" text="Comment" />
         </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Button id="editLuggage" fx:id="editLuggage" layoutX="1030.0" layoutY="122.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#editSelected" text="Edit selected luggage" />
      <Button id="deleteLuggage" fx:id="deleteLuggage" layoutX="120.0" layoutY="55.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadLuggageTable" onMouseClicked="#loadLuggageTable" text="Fetch ALL Luggage" />
      <Button id="editLuggage" fx:id="editLuggage1" layoutX="1007.0" layoutY="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#editSelected" text="Remove selected luggage" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

So what happens is that when I switch from the LuggageMenuScherm.FXML to the Editluggage.FXML using the open method from the Class Popup with all the parameters it crashes as soon as I try to change an item such as the TextField with for example the setText(). As soon as I remove the editWeight.setText("sdfsfsdf") in the editSelected method in the controller the scene pops up and works. I would appreciate help trying to get this issue solved so that I can set the text of the items on that FXML page. Also both scene's use the **same** controller.

Comment: BTW: You don't need to specify `id`, if you use the same `fx:id`. The `fx:id` will be assigned to the `id` property.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `editWeight` hasn't initialized. I guess that your current scene is `LuggageMenuScherm.FXML` because in the `editSelected()` method the code is going to load `Editluggage.FXML`. However, in `LuggageMenuScherm.FXML`, there's no component which id is `editWeight`.

---

By the way, I suggest that don't use one controller in common.

---

**Update**

Remove the `fx:controller` attribute in the `Editluggage.FXML`, and try the following codes.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(<FXML file>);
loader.setController(this);
Parent node = loader.load();
```

or

```
public void open(String scene, String title, Class className, Object controller, Button btn) {
    // Add a controller param
    try {
        Stage stage;
        Parent root;

        stage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(className.getResource(scene));
        loader.setController(controller); // Set default controller
        root = loader.load();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        stage.initOwner(btn.getScene().getWindow());
        stage.showAndWait();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(luggageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

---

**Update 2**

In my implement of Application class, there's a method which is used to change the scene. There may be other better way to do this.

```
public void changeScene(Scene scene, String title) {
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    setTitle(title);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: @EmOwn Both FXML documents use the same controller which you can see in the above code `fx:controller="fastenyourseatbelt.view.luggageController"` the editWeight is the TextField with the fx:id="editWeight" which you see in the Editluggage.FXML file. Since this FXML file uses the same controller the editWeight should be initialized in the controller. My suspicion is that something with the Scene and/or Stage is wrong.

Comment: And I know that the `editWeight` is both in `luggageController` and `Editluggage.FXML`, but it doesn't appear in `LuggageMenuScherm.FXML`, while your current loaded FXML is `LuggageMenuScherm.FXML`, not `Editluggage.FXML.

Comment: And you are trying to load a new node from `Editluggage.FXML` by calling `popup.open()`, but even though they set the same controller class, they're controller instance are not the same one.

Comment: Oh okay, how would I solve this? and this is what my Launch looks like:   `public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }`

Comment: I mean the `Application.start(Stage)` method.

Comment: To solve it, delete `editWeight.setText("sdfsfsdf");` this line.

Comment: This is the start method: http://prntscr.com/dh4a19 and removing the editWeight still doesn't solve my issue because I want to be able to change the text with setText but need to know how.

Comment: You mean that you want to change the text of the `editWeight` right?

Comment: You can try `FXMLLoader.setController` to set the specific controller to the FXML that you are going to load. See my update.

Comment: The error is now gone with the editWeight being in the editSelected(). However it does not run any of the code below even a System.out.println() does not appear if I place it below the popup.open().

Comment: Because in `popup.open()`, there's `stage.showAndWait()`, so until you close that stage, there won't be any output

Comment: Don't create a new stage. Instead, use `stage.setScene()`

Comment: Just create a new scene from FXML, `new Scene(<loaded FXML node>)`, and use `stage.setScene()`

Comment: In my implement of `Application` class, there's a method which is used to change the scene